# Do all planets in Stargate series have exactly the same atmospheric pressure?

Tags: stargate, stargate-movie

In *Stargate* (the movie) we see that, when the gate is activated, there is no wind moving from one planet to another. This suggests that air does not flow, which, in turn suggests atmospheric pressure is the same in both locations.

Is it that way? And for all planets through the series as well?

If not, why is there no wind?

Comment: opening the stargate is not like opening a window, remember you cant see the other side through the gate, you step into a wormhole that then moves you across space to exit out of a second gate, the wormhole surface may even be able for air to diffuse through it. otherwise to answer your main questions, no the planets are typically all in a similar range as extremes tend to be unhospitable for human life, however there are many planets that do have more extreme temperaments in the series. i believe we have seen storms on 1 of the gate, yet no water is let through the gate.

Comment: It goes without saying that the out of universe explanation is that all planets in the series (the surfaces, anyway) are filmed on Earth, and nobody thought about different planets having different atmospheric pressures.

Comment: That was a real problem in Lester del Rey's story "The Wind Between the Worlds".

Comment: Clarke's 3rd law - Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: Um, aren't the gates one-way only for matter?

Comment: And if they are not the same, why don't humans who travel through them have pressure effects on their health?

Comment: @Dronz Pressure itself isn't really too important, we're pretty resistant to that. It's the partial pressure of certain gases (like oxygen) that's important - and presumably, that was taken care of to be at least tolerable by the terra-formers (be it the Ancients or the Goauld). Note that the Earth plants themselves would tend to balance at the same partial pressure of oxygen we like, mostly (too much gives you forest fires, too little improves oxygen production).

Comment: @KyleKanos - One-way for matter, yes. But the problem remains. Why would you never see a strong wind blowing through the StarGate in that one direction when they come through. A small difference in air pressure should cause a pretty strong wind, either going to the planet or coming back, depending on which side has the stronger pressure.

Comment: @OCDev: Last I checked, air is made up of particles (i.e., matter), so there's no way that air could be coming *from* the other planet.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Last I checked, humans are made up of particles (i.e., matter), so if humans can return _from_ the planet, then air particles can also come _from_ the planet while the humans are returning.

Comment: @KyleKanos: But also, same thing can be said about going _to_ the planet. _From_ or _to_ is not the issue. The side with the higher pressure is the issue. 1. Stargate opens. 2. Matter goes through one-way. Why doesn't the higher air pressure from one or the other ever show air blowing through? It should be seen occasionally, up to half the time. (Depending on which side has the higher air pressure determines the occasion that you'll see the air blowing through--if the receiving side has the higher pressure, true, you won't see it. But if the sending side does, you should see it.)

Comment: @OCDev: I imagine that if the "going-to" gate is at a lower pressure then the "from-here" gate, there might be a wind *seen at the "going-to" planet*--but in-universe rules say it **cannot** be the other way around. And in the absence of freely-moving objects (e.g., a tree), such a wind would not be noticable.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Yes, this is precisely what I was saying when I said, "if the receiving side has the higher pressure, true, you won't see it." I think, however, the wind would often be rather strong and be noticeable in the flapping of their clothing, hair, and even strong enough to cause them to fall over on occasion. Consider that heat from building fires is enough to cause windows to explosively blow outward, which is quite a burst of air for a modest difference in pressure. Humans should be able to visit planets with atmospheres of pressure many times ours, which is a much bigger differential.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Matter doesn't move between planets due to pressure *differential*! The planets are connected by a wormhole and separated by a matter-energy-matter conversion sequence, so the rules of fluid dynamics do not have any bearing on the behaviour of either air or water in terms of how/whether they transit through the gate.

What *is* relevant is the threshold of pressure exerted upon the gate's event horizon before the gate decides to dematerialise that particular matter and send it through. It was explained in *SG1: Watergate* that standard atmosphere pressure (at least) is under this threshold, and we saw in *ATL: The Shrine* fear that water (with its pressure against the gate mostly coming from the sheer weight of a massive body of the stuff) is over that threshold and could flood the area around the receiving gate. This makes sense, since the pressure of an ocean is greater than the pressure of a random SG team member walking casually up to the event horizon, and obviously we know that *they* get through.

The other obvious counter-example is Atlantis dialling space-gates and the air not being immediately sucked out of the gate room.

That being said, the planets we've seen that actually have a breathable atmosphere appear to have one at standard Earth ground-level pressure (or, at least, roughly within Earth's usual variation) because nobody's complained about their ears popping or their eyes being pushed back into their skulls.

Comment: I think the Atlantis episode with keeping the shield active was just fear/safety.  If the water would have flowed into the gate, it should have been hitting the shield on the receiving side and had a visible flow on the sending side.  So it does match the other episodes, if the pressure basis is upon gate activation rather than all time.

Comment: @Izkata: True; and actually that lines up with Carter's comments that the gate will "just know" that such high constant pressure is unlikely to be desirable. I still don't think we have any evidence that this has anything to do with _comparative_ pressures, though. And, even if it does, it would have to be a logical mechanism in the gate because fluid dynamics themselves cannot be responsible here.

Comment: "sucked out?" You mean blown out. lol

Comment: @fredsbend: Cheers, Data!

Comment: +1, excellent point.  The reason pressure differential matters in real-world physics is because the transfer of particles is always two-way.  Since the Stargate only transfers matter one-way, the differential is irrelevant.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Quite right :D

Comment: @fredsbend: Actually, to be fair, I think the air _is_ sucked. The distinction is that everything else is instead "blown" because it's the air being sucked that drags stuff with it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I honestly don't know which term is better, or even if one can be. You can see what's up on space.se: [Is the air "sucked out" or "blown out" into space when the hatch opens?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5947)

Comment: @fredsbend: And the posts on that page echo what I said.

Answer (score 39):

The stargates have some safeties built in. One of which is handling differential pressures.  In the *SG-1* episode *[Watergate](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Watergate_%28episode%29)*, we see a particularly egregious example.  In the episode, a stargate is on Earth, another is underwater on a distant planet.  When they connect the two from Earth's side, water does not start rushing into the gate on the distant planet.  When they connect from the distant planet's side, the same does not happen.  A sub is used to travel safely between the two planets, and the stargates enable the sub to safely cross, but there's no deluge of water.

The same thing (to a much lesser extant) happens with differing air pressures.

Comment: There are plenty of examples in SG:Atlantis of Star Gates being in orbit, with no sudden massive world ending decompression when they travel through one to another planet whose SG isn't in orbit :)

Comment: In such case, how does the stargate know that it needs to allow passing of water in your body but not ambient water?

Comment: @Envite I haven't watched "Watergate" in a while, but I dimly remember some technobabble about how the water exerts a constant pressure on the wormhole; the gate lets the sub through because it exerts sudden pressure

Comment: Advanced alien tech knows the difference.

Comment: @Moo I figured a Milky Way example would be best, since that's the galaxy the question asks about.  Those are a good example, though.

Comment: Also, in SG:A Inferno, a sudden increase in constant pressure might be let through. I seem to recall Sheppard radioing Atlantis to put the gate shield up when the remote gate fell in the lava.

Comment: Even though it seems that water and air don't traverse the worm hole, there are many examples of explosions, bullets, weapons blasts, and gravity (remember the black hole problem) going through just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy Bullets are **enormous** compared to water or air molecules.

Comment: I would point out that the stargates apparently do allow gravity through, as shown in the sg1 episode where they open a gate that is close to a black hole and nearly destroy sg1 and the entire earth, complete with time dilatation and everything. http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/A_Matter_of_Time

Comment: @rmaddy Also, all of those examples are items with momentum. Stagnant water does not have momentum, and as was pointed out, is not subject to pressure differences between gate environments because there cannot be any. Except gravity. I don't know enough about physics to say why gravity should be any different than light. Also, Radio EM passes through, which from what I understand *is* light. The gates obviously use smart filtering.

Comment: @fredsbend or, the show's science is riddled with wormholes.

Comment: @Gusdor As a serious Stargate fan, I don't think I could accept that position.

Comment: @Moo Wow, imagine the wall of air collisions the Puddle-jumpers experience every-time they return at huge speeds from those space-based gates.

Comment: @fredsbend i wouldn't want you to. There is lots of fun to be had in there!

Comment: To be fair, _it wasn't water_.

Answer (score 2):

Also worth noting is the sg1 episode "a matter of time" where the gate connects to a planet near a black hole. Samantha sees smoke being sucked into the gate. The only time I've ever seen gases going through the gate.
http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/A_Matter_of_Time

In this instance think it would be better to say that proximity to black holes messes up the stargate, rather than gravity can suck gases through the gate.

Comment: Gravity totally "sucks gases". How do you think Earth's atmosphere stays ... y'know, on Earth? That's precisely why smoke went through the gate.

Comment: Gravity sucks thing more or less depending on their mass, so if the gravity is enough to suck a gas it should in theory suck all masive objects in the room a million times harder...
But it's a classic TV tropes that physical forces apply when and where they want in TV (like a hurricane sucking a truck but not the man beside it...)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted about the SG1 episode "Watergate" the stargate must screen out ambient pressure somehow in an unspecified way.

More specifically concerning whether every planet in the gate system has the same atmospheric pressure the answer is domonstrably "no." In the SG1 episode "Message in a bottle" the team uses full NASA style space suites to explore structures on the surface of an airless world. Presumably there are other planets with air pressures in between 1 atm and 0 atm.